# Scrape relevant information from soup file

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape url to obtain the address and branch_name for all the branches.

URL="https://www.uob.co.id/personal/branch-and-atm-locator.page"

From the network option, I found the requested url path as:
URL="https://www.uob.co.id/wsm/stayinformed.do?path=lokasicabangatm"
but the format in which data is present here isn't clear.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
print(soup)
```

How can I extract the relevant information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just dump the response to a `.csv` file and there you have all the data.

```
import requests

headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36",
}
response = requests.get("https://www.uob.co.id/wsm/stayinformed.do?path=lokasicabangatm", headers=headers).text
with open("data.csv", "w") as f:
    f.write(response)
```

Output:

[image]